# Calculating the images of transformations of matrices

Tags: matrices

$f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $f(a,b) = (a+b, 2a-b, a-2b)$. Find the kernel and the image.

I found the kernel to be $\ker(f) = \{(0,0)\}$ but cannot get the right image. The book says the image should be $\operatorname{im}(f)= L\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)\}$, does someone understand how this image was obtained?

Comment: What did you get for the image? Remember that two different sets of vectors can have the same span, so you might have written down the correct set even if you didn't choose $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ as a basis.

Comment: I got L{(1,2,1), (1,-1,-2)}...

Comment: And indeed, these two linear spaces are equal. For example, $(1,0,-1)+2(0,1,1)=(1,2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

From rank nullity theorem,you have dimension of Image space is 2.Now you can choose any two linearly independent vectors of the form  (a+b, 2a-b, a-2b).